# How do I return a partcular string if column value is null MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I return a particular string if column value is null MySQL? So basically in the instance below sometimes the values "tableA.Name" is sometimes Null as the user has forgot to fill it.

In this case rather than returning Null, I'd like some sort of if statement to check if the value is null then say "Name not assigned"

My MySQL query:

```
SELECT `shoes_item`.Product_Name, `run_task`.Name, `shoes_item`.Notes FROM `shoes_item` As test
LEFT OUTER JOIN `run_item`
ON `run_item`.shoes_ID = `shoes_item`.shoes_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN `run_details`
ON `run_details`.run_Item_ID = `run_item`.run_Item_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is his what you are looking for?

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(`shoes_item`.Product_Name,"name not assigned") as product_name, `run_task`.Name, `shoes_item`.Notes FROM `shoes_item` As test
LEFT OUTER JOIN `run_item`
ON `run_item`.shoes_ID = `shoes_item`.shoes_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN `run_details`
ON `run_details`.run_Item_ID = `run_item`.run_Item_ID
```

Comment: You're answer has worked fantastically. Apparently I've got to wait 4 minutes to accept it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
select coalesce(tableA.name, 'Name not assigned') as name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFNULL` function

For example `IFNULL(tableA.Name,'Name not assigned')`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem by using the mysql if condition, it will solve both the issue like the column is null or blank.

**The query will be.**

```
select if(tableA.Name IS NULL || tableA.Name=' ','Name not assigned',tableA.Name)

as Name from tableA;
```